# Make Microsoft Add-In area larger when running my Add-In in OneNote online?

Tags: office-js, office-addins, onenote, onenote-api

I have created an Add-In for OneNote, online version.  It works fine except I can't seem to figure out how to make the area that OneNote provides for my Add-In wider (consume more screen real estate).  I need more than the narrow column provided because I am displaying a wide graphic with my user interface.  Right now the user has to scroll the narrow column left and right, too much so to provide a usable interface.

Note, I used the Yeoman Scaffolding tools to initially create my add-in.

How can I make the Add-In panel/column wider from my code?  Is there a OneNote API or Microsoft Graph/Fabric API call I can use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I do not think this is possible at this time. However, you can request this feature here: https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-api